# How to decide number of segments per host/node in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I am setting up prod cluster and want to choose number of segments per host/node, how to decide this? And what is the benefits to have multiple primary segments (excluding mirror) per node?

Comment: A single query usually does not consume all available CPU resources on the segment. Having more primary segments will allow the use of more, or all CPUs. The rule of thumb is that you go with as many segments as CPU cores. Half that number if you have mirrors enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this guide... specifically page 22

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43100/pdf/Pivotal_Clustering_Concepts_A03.pdf

hope this helps..

Comment: As per doc only benefit is maximum utilization of system resources.